# how to return the number of words in the string "sentence"

Tags: c++

I am new to coding and I want to know how to count the number of words, in the "sentence". This function uses a class, what variable should I use to return? Do I have to increment "i" to move to the next character?

```
int Directive::words(const char* sentence) {
    int i, word = 0;

    for (i = 0; sentence[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if ((sentence[i] >= 'a' && sentence[i] <= 'z') || (sentence[i] >= 'A' && sentence[i] <= 'Z')) {
            i++;
            if (sentence[i] != ' ' && sentence[i] != '\n' && sentence[i] != '\t') {
                word++;
                i++;
            }
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }
    return word;
}
```

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages. Select one language tag.

Comment: There are no classes in C, so this must be C++.

Comment: That or some truly insane macro abuse...

Comment: Recommendation: see if you can take advantage of `tolower` and `isalpha` to save yourself some work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence must end with a '\0'

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int GetWordsCount(const char * Sentencee){
    int Count = 0;
    int LetterCount = 0;

    while (*Sentencee++){
        if (isspace(*Sentencee) || *Sentencee == '.' || *Sentencee == ',' || *Sentencee == '\0'){
            if (LetterCount)
                Count++;

            LetterCount = 0;
        }
        else
            LetterCount++;
    }

    return Count;
}

int main() 
{ 
    const char * Sentencee = "Hello, i am learning c++!";
    cout << "Sentence: " << Sentencee << endl;
    cout << "count: " << GetWordsCount(Sentencee) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```